# How to handle exception while using spring kafka asyncAck

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-kafka

I have a requirement to process kafka messages in at-least-once fashion. Spring kafka supports async ack starting from 2.8 version.
I am storing received offsets from kafka in a map and after message processing is done committing kafka offsets. This all working fine until i send any error event(poison pill). I am not able to commit bad record inside error handler and due to this kafka is not consuming any new records after encountering any bad/malformed record.

code for kafka listener factory:

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JsonNode> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, JsonNode> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JsonNode> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAsyncAcks(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

Error Handler Code:

```
  @Bean("errorHandler")
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        log.info("Creating error handler");
        return (thrownException, records) -> {
            log.error("Inside error handler");
        };
    }
```

ErrorHandler is marked as Deprecated. Even in CommonErrorHandler I am not able to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to acknowledge all records before the next batch is fetched (even the poison pill).

You will have to ack it in the listener before throwing the exception.

Comment: I am using KafkaListenerErrorHandler as following

`
@Bean("kafkaListenErrorHandler")
    public ManualAckListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler() {
        return (message, exception, consumer, ack) -> {
            log.info("Inside manual ack error handler " + exception.getMessage());
            exception.printStackTrace();
            ack.acknowledge();
            return null;
        };
    }`

Added errorHandler in kafka listener
@KafkaListener(errorHandler = "kafkaListenErrorHandler")

but not able to handle deserialisation error inside kafkaListenErrorHandler

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. No, deserialization errors occur much earlier, use an `ErrrorHandlingDeserializer` to send such problems to the common error handler.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer